# UK Transit Visa from Pakistan

Tags: uk, transit, manchester

I have student visa of Sweden. I'm applying for UK transit visa. Just confused that if i get visa and go UK airport, immigration officer can make problem for me and will not let me allow to cross uk border controls. If i get visa, then my visa will be valid for 48 hours and i will be officially allowed to cross uk border controls. but just worried if immigration officer can make problem for me?

I am from Pakistan.

Comment: Yes, the border control officer "can make problem for you", but then the same is true for everyone else. The question you should be asking is, is there anything about you that might cause the officer to look twice at you? If you are only worried because of your nationality and what you may have read here and other places, please note that the mass media covers the 1% of bad and not the 99% of people who are just waved through, since they aren't a _story_. Be calm, cool, and look like you belong (not nervous) and you'll be fine. Of course, if you're really a mass murderer, then...

Answer (score 1):

They do not revoke transit visas on a whim.  There needs to be a concrete reason like you obtained it fraudulently or you are using forged documents.  The law says that a transit visa means the Home Office has already checked you out and you are cleared.  From the [rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/449508/20150803_immigration_rules_part_1_final.pdf)...

> The holder of such an entry clearance will not require leave to enter
>   on arrival in the United Kingdom and, for the purposes of these Rules,
>   will be treated as a person who has arrived in the United Kingdom with
>   leave to enter the United Kingdom which is in force but which was
>   given to him before his arrival.

An Immigration Officer's discretionary latitude in these cases is very slim, if any.

If your nervous behaviour sets off the IO's radar, they may pursue a more intrusive line of questioning.  Even then if you have played it straight up, there is nothing to worry about.